# VSCode Extension embedding an image in editor area

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to write an extension for VSCode that searches for a certain word in the text file you are editing and replaces that word with an image in the editors view. Once you click on the image it should transform back into the original text, and become editable like usual.

I was hopeful that this would be possible, but after discovering that VSCode doesn't let you manipulate the DOM directly, I am doubtful.

Could someone point me to some documentation that would enable me to add images to the editor window? (and not the line-number area on the left)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Update: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/66418 It is now implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VSCode does not support custom UI, but [text decorators](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions) may work in your case. Here's an example extension that shows how to use them: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/decorator-sample

To display an image using decorators, try `contentIconPath` on `ThemableDecorationAttachmentRenderOptions`

Comment: Could you go about creating a canvas behind the text? I have an idea for an extension, but I don't know if I should even try if it's impossible :/

Comment: No, extensions cannot access the editor dom to insert a canvas or other elements

Comment: @MattBierner based on your last comment I guess that it is not possible to implement something like this https://twitter.com/giuseppegurgone/status/1108991817024983041 right? The expanded code block would be another editor view that displays the content of the dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Since I always wanted to have this solution myself, I just created a VS Code extension. Although VS Code doesn't allow inline images, it can show them in a tool tip. That's also quite useful for code documentation:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgiesen.image-comments